# This array formula is not working

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

Hi following formula is working, but array formula is not working.

Working EQ:
=IF(V2:V=1,INDEX($E$2:$E,MATCH(T2&B2&"Delivered Time (Today)",$T$2:$T&$B$2:$B&$C$2:$C,0)),"")

I wonder, but this formula is not working:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(V2:V=1,INDEX($E$2:$E,MATCH(T2&B2&"Delivered Time (Today)",$T$2:$T&$B$2:$B&$C$2:$C,0)),""))

Can someone educate me to fix this?

Example details:
[Example Sheet is here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hONPXRvZa9zQYs6LRLzB9jtj70gFkh44ZQ6LUeyDJOE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: You should post some example to work with so that we can reproduce the error.

Comment: Sure thanks, I am updating.

Comment: Hi, Please check once. I have attached google sheet reference.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not all Sheets functions work within an arrayformula, and INDEX and MATCH are two that do not

Instead, you can use VLOOKUP and construct an array to do the job of INDEX/MATCH:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(V2:V=1,VLOOKUP(T2:T&B2:B&"Delivered Time (Today)",{T2:T&B2:B&C2:C,E2:E},2,0),))`

You can it working in this copy of your example sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dFVNfPn0R9goQaLjRvZEwggRthbkEY3nC3aqC2joPcw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you very much Man!

It made me move to the next. I am stuck there from a couple of weeks. But I didn't understand why it is not working.